# How to set the number of knots in a regression spline

Tags: r, regression, splines

I want to fit fit a cubic regression spline and select the optimal number of knots via grid search. In other words, I want to find the optimal number of knots that minimizes the average test Mean Squared Error of
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \beta_2 X_i^2 + \beta_3 X_i^3 + \beta_{3+1} (X_i - c_1)_+^3 + ... + \beta_{3 + k} (X_i - c_k)_+^3$$
where $k$ is the number of knots in the domain of $X$.

I am using R for this task. However, I am not sure which parameter in `step_bs` sets the degree of the polynomial and which one sets the number of knots. Here's what I have so far:

```r
# Libraries
library(tidymodels)
library(ISLR)

# Load data and split it into 10 folds
df <- Wages
cv <- vfold_cv(data = df, v = 10)

# Spline recipe
rec_spline <- recipe(formula = wage ~ maritl + age, data = df) %>%
  step_bs(age, deg_free = tune()) # I only want to tune the number of knots for `age`

# Workflow
spline_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(lm_spec) %>%
  add_recipe(rec_spline)

# Step grid
spline_grid = data.frame(deg_free = c(1:10)) # Is this the number of cuts?

# Fit step-functions on grid
spline_tune <- tune_grid(object = spline_wf, resamples = cv, grid = spline_grid)
```

It is my understanding that a regression spline has $(d + 1) + k$ degrees of freedom, where $d$ is the degree of the polynomial (in this case 3 because it's cubic) and $K$ is the number of cuts in the domain of $X$.

I cannot specify $d$ and $k$ by passing a single integer as `deg_free`. So how can I make sure that the spline is cubic and make the number of knots the tuning parameter?

Comment: This approach is very involved and does not result in proper uncertainty intervals.  Why not just choose the number of knots based on (1) what the effective sample size will support and (2) subject matter knowledge?  Details in [Chapter 2 of RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms).

Comment: I realize it's a little overkill for such a simple data set. However, I was specifically asked to find the best number of knots using CV as homework, haha.

Comment: It's definitely possible; you just lose a lot of statistical inferential capabilities when doing that.